# Does Google consider my blog page as duplicate page if that page URL and that page URL with ‘showcomment’ cached separately?

Tags: duplicate-content, blogger, google-cache

While I’m searching all the index page of my blog I found that Google cached one of my blog page http://example.com/page.html

as well as

http://example.com/page.html?showComment=1372054729698

These two pages are showing while I searched site:http://example.com. I’m so afraid about it because these two pages are same with same content. Does google consider these two pages as duplicate?  If so what can I do now? Is it really a big problem to my blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since multiple URLs can be used to pull up the same content you need to use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to tell Google which one is the primary URL. In your case it would be:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/page.html" />
```

Comment: Where i have to put this code? I know Canonical tag should be placed on the header tag of a page but in blogspot every post don't have header tags.

Comment: That i don't know as i don't use blogger. But since Google owns it there has to be a way to get this done. Hopefully someone can chime in with what that is.

Comment: @JohnSanjay If you're using blogspot check to confirm that Google's not already inserting canonical links there. I checked a friend's blogspot and it has canonical in the header. If it's already there and Google's still caching both I wouldn't worry about it.